# Issue while trying to echo a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function doConnect()
{
   $trueServer = "X";
   $trueDb = "X";
   $trueUser = "X";
   $truePassword = "X";
    mysql_connect($trueServer, $trueUser, $truePassword) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($trueDb) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
} 

$currentlang = $_SESSION['lang'];

function my()
{
   global $pnew;
   global $pnewLine;
   global $pnX;
   global $currentlang;
   doConnect();
   $pnew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE cat='ppn' AND lang='".$currentlang."' ORDER BY id DESC");
   while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
   {
      $pnX = $line['text'];
   }
   echo $pnX;
}

my();

?>
```

I'm trying to select a table row and echo it, if I use it without the `my();` function it works just like a charm, instead it just doesn't echo.

*Now you ask me: why don’t you remove these functions and use pure PHP instead? A: I’m using the `include` function (I don’t know its real name) and it is working pretty fine.*

By the way, the `doConnect();` function is working fine. So far I've tried using global variables but it is still not working.  Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Where are you assigning the rows to $pnewLine, but then using $line.

Comment: change `while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew)) {$pnX = $line['text'];}` TO `while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew)) {$pnX = $pnewLine['text'];}`

Comment: replaced it by pnewLine and it is still not working :\

Comment: it's because it's an array. Use `print_r($pnX);` instead of `echo $pnX;`

Answer (score 3):

Please check your function. Here you are not retrieving data from you array of while loop

```
function my()
{
   global $pnew;
   global $pnewLine;
   global $pnX;
   global $currentlang;
   doConnect();
   $pnew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE cat='ppn' AND lang='".$currentlang."'    ORDER BY id DESC");
   while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
   {
         $pnX = $pnewLine['text'];
   }
   echo $pnX;   //if this is array then it won't printed.
   print_r($pnX);   //try this to print instead

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**at first stop using `mysql_` use `mysqli_` or `pdo`**

i think you need a `foreach`

```
foreach($pnx as $pn)
{
    echo $pn;
}
```

**lastly, stop using `mysql_` use `mysqli_` or `pdo`**

Comment: +1 for 
> stop using mysql_ use mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: The Mysql function is just working fine without the function that I made...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pnew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE cat='ppn' AND lang='".$currentlang."' ORDER BY id DESC");
if ($pnew) {
  list($pnX) = mysql_fetch_row($pnew);
  echo $pnX;
}
```

There's no point with the loop if you're only expecting 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
```

what this actually means is that

```
while(the variable $pnewLine receives the value of mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
{
    // Always executed
}
```

Meanwhile

```
while($pnewLine = mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
```

actually means

```
while(the variable $pnewLine is equal to the value of mysql_fetch_array($pnew))
{
    // Not always executed
}
```

You spot the difference?